# Download YouTube video in c# and discord.net

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, discord.net

I am creating a discord bot and it should be able to play music from youtube. I've already created the code to play music but i still need to download the music. When I download it I get this output:

```
Downloading (VIDEO NAME) - YouTube.mp4 to C:\Users\Laurin\source\repos\DiscordBot\DiscordBot\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x64
Downloaded. Saving to disk
16:46:15 Gateway     A MessageReceived handler is blocking the gateway task.
```

My current code:

```
[Command("yt")]
    public async Task ytCommand([Remainder] string url)
    {
        SaveVideoToDisk(url);
    }

    void SaveVideoToDisk(string link)
    {
        var youTube = YouTube.Default; // starting point for YouTube actions
        var video = youTube.GetVideo(link); // gets a Video object with info about the video
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading " + video.FullName + " to " + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        byte[] bytes = video.GetBytes();
        Console.WriteLine("Downloaded. Saving to disk");
        File.WriteAllBytes(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + video.FullName, bytes);
    }
```

I'm using [libvideo/VideoLibrary](https://github.com/i3arnon/libvideo) to download the video

Comment: Why does this question have a down vote?

Comment: @Unknown I don't know either

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it has to do with the fact you have not asked a question, therefore you are wasting everyone's time with this post as there is no way to answer it. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of downloading the video, you can use [Youtube Explode](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode), To get the Stream object and pipe the stream into ffmpeg.

Edit: System.Diagnostics.process does not do well with Piping So I used [Cliwrap](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliWrap)

Code to get a stream from a youtube video

```
YoutubeClient youtube = new YoutubeClient()
var StreamManifest = await youtube.Videos.GetManifestAsync()
var StreamInfo = await StreamManifest.GetAudioOnly().WithHighestBitrate();
var stream = youtube.Videos.Streams.GetAsync(StreamInfo)
```

Code to allow pipe to stdin and get the Stdout.

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await Cli.Wrap("ffmpeg")
            .WithArguments(" -hide_banner -loglevel panic -i pipe:0 -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1")
            .WithStandardInputPipe(PipeSource.FromStream(strean))
            .WithStandardOutputPipe(PipeTarget.ToStream(memoryStream))
            .ExecuteAsync();
```

Play Memory Stream To Discord!

```
using (var discord = AudioClient.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Mixed))
        {
            try {await AudioClient.WriteAsync(memoryStream.ToArray(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length); }
            finally { await AudioClient.FlushAsync(); }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the command runmode to async so it doesn't hold anything up :

`[Command("yt", RunMode = RunMode.Async)]`

Comment: Thank you, I'm new in discord bot programming, so I didn't know that

Comment: Now I have this: `Downloading (VIDEO NAME) - YouTube.mp4 to C:\Users\Laurin\Source\Repos\LaneBot\LaneBot\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x64
06:25:39 Gateway     System.Exception: Server missed last heartbeat
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Discord.ConnectionManager.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<<StartAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
06:25:39 Gateway     Disconnecting` Do you know how II can fix it?

Comment: I recommend you open another question, or join the discord api server : https://discord.gg/discord-api and ask in the `#dotnet_discord-net` channel.

Answer (score 0):

Requesting and downloading the video needs to run asynchronously so that it doesn't hold up the gateway handler.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html